how to capture CLI output for specific variable in firebase app distribution CLI
how to capture testing_uri from CLI output as described in this documentation for firebase app distribution. Is testing_uri exposed as environment variable or should i just parse the output with some custom regex and grab the uri
this is the output that i get for CLI command firebase appdistribution:distribute
removing specific uris for privacy but this is the output format doesn't have a variable like testing_uri
i want to grab the uri after "Share this release with testers who have access:"
View this release in the Firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project.....
Share this release with testers who have access: https://appdistribution.firebase.google.com/testerapps/.....
Download the release binary (link expires in 1 hour): uri....


The testing_uri is not exposed as an environment variable for the firebase app distribution. Like you mentioned, you will need to parse the output with regex to obtain the desired uri. I can help with a bash script that will execute the firebase appdistribution:distribute and export the TESTING_URI to an environment variable.


#!/bin/bash

# Run the Firebase App Distribution command
output=$(firebase appdistribution:distribute <your-app-path> --app <your-app-id> --token <your-token>)

# Use regex to find the testing URI in the output
uri=$(echo "$output" | grep -oE "https://appdistribution\.firebase\.google\.com/testerapps/[a-zA-Z0-9]+")

# Check if the URI pattern as described above was matched
if [ -n "$uri" ]; then
    echo "Testing URI found: $uri"
    # Export the URI as an environment variable
    export TESTING_URI="$uri"
    echo "TESTING_URI is now set as an environment variable"
else
    echo "Testing URI not found in the output"
fi



Save the bash script above with a name of your choice ending in .sh.
You can name it get_firebase_testing_uri.sh.
Make the script executable with the command below:


chmod +x get_firebase_testing_uri.sh



Run the bash script with the command below:


./get_firebase_testing_uri.sh



Obtain the exported environment variable with echo as shown below:


echo $TESTING_URI



I hope this works!
